# How to add an optional column inside struct field with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I currently had created a struct field in this way:

```
df = df.withColumn('my_struct', struct(
col('id').alias('id_test')
col('value').alias('value_test')
).alias('my_struct'))
```

The think is that now I need to add and extra field to my_struct called "optional". This field must be there when it exits and remove it when it's not. Sadly values like null/none not an option.

So far I have two different dataframes, one with the desired value and the column by id and another one without the value/column and all the information.

```
df_optional = df_optional.select('id','optional')
df = df.select('id','value','my_struct')
```

I want to add into df.my_struct the optional value when df_optional.id join df.join plus the rest.
Till this point I have this:

```
df_with_option = df.join(df_optional,on=['id'],how='inner') \
.withColumn('my_struct', struct(
    col('id').alias('id_test')
    col('value').alias('value_test')
    col(optional).alias('optional')
    ).alias('my_struct')).drop('optional')
df_without = df.join(df_optional,on=['id'],how='leftanti') # it already have my_struct
```

But union should have similar columns so my code breaks.

```
df_result = df_without .unionByName(df_with_option)
```

I want to union both dataframes because at the end I write a json file partitioned by id:

```
df_result.repartitionByRange(df_result.count(),df['id']).write.format('json').mode('overwrite').save('my_path')
```

Those json files should have the 'optional' column when it has values, otherwise it should be out of the schema.

Any help will be appreciate.

**--ADITIONAL INFO.**

Schema input:

```
df_root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- optional: string (nullable = true)

df_optional
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_struct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Schema output:

```
df_result
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_struct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- optional: string (nullable = true) (*)
```

(*) Only when it exists.

**--UPDATE**
I think that it jsut not posible in that way. I probably need to keep both dataframes appart and just write it two times. Something like this:

```
df_without.repartitionByRange(df_result.count(),df['id']).write.format('json').mode('overwrite').save('my_path')
df_with_option.repartitionByRange(df_result.count(),df['id']).write.format('json').mode('append').save('my_path')
```

Then I will had in my path the files by it's own way.

Comment: Can you share how the input datafram looks like and what exactly you want to achieve? I.e how the output should be?

Comment: that optional element must be added after joining? if not you can just check if second df contains optional field and then add or not optional to struct

Comment: @dsk I update the post with the schemas.

Comment: @chlebek In my first approach yes, I want to add it If I cant to write one time only. But I think that this is just not the way to goin on. I updated it with something that should work.